# Maven: How to get all transitive dependencies programatically in a MOJO

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-plugin, mojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get access to Maven’s dependency hierarchy within a plugin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492000/how-to-get-access-to-mavens-dependency-hierarchy-within-a-plugin)

The dependency:tree plugin:goal has an option 'verbose' which displays all conflicts & duplicates in the dependency tree. I am trying to reuse that information in my own mojo to generate reports, however - I can't seem to figure out exactly how that plugin is gathering all transitive dependencies\artifacts.

I've tried:

```
ArtifactResolutionResult result = _artifactCollector.collect( _project.getDependencyArtifacts(), _project.getArtifact(), _project.getManagedVersionMap(),
            _localRepository, _project.getRemoteArtifactRepositories(), _artifactMetadataSource, null, Collections.EMPTY_LIST );
```

As far as I can tell this is how the tree goal is doing it with the exception of the listener.

Does anyone out there know how to do what I am asking?

UPDATE: I didn't search well enough apparently, my question is a duplicate of:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492000/how-to-get-access-to-mavens-dependency-hierarchy-within-a-plugin). Please vote to close as I have already done, thanks.