# Maven: get all dependencies programmatically

Tags: java, maven, aether

How can I programmatically get all dependencies of a Maven module outside a Maven execution environment?

So far I have:

via maven-core:

```
Path pomPath = ...;
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(pomPath)) {
    Model model = reader.read(is);
    this.mavenProject = new MavenProject(model);
}
```

and via jcabi-aether:

```
File localRepo = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".m2").toFile();
new Classpath(mavenProject, localRepo, "runtime")
```

Is this generally correct so far?

The issue now is that I'm getting a NullPointerException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.mrepos(Aether.java:197)
    at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.<init>(Aether.java:140)
    at com.jcabi.aether.Classpath.<init>(Classpath.java:125)
```

since mavenProject.getRemoteProjectRepositories() returns null.

How can I initialze the MavenProject to contain the configured remote repos taking the settings.xml file (mirrors, proxies, repositories etc.) into account as well?

Comment: I don't think this is going in the right direction. Take a look at [`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) instead

Comment: If you don't have the POM file, and only have coordinates, you can look into Aether. To fetch direct dependencies with Aether, [you can refer to this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638138/find-all-direct-dependencies-of-an-artifact-on-maven-central). If you do have the POM, then using `dependency:get -Dtransitive=false` will get the direct dependencies in a much easier way. Take a look at the [Invoker API](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/)

Comment: To clarify: I do have a POM file but the code runs outside a Maven execution. I want to populate a URLClassLoader with the URLs to the dependencies in the local repo (which might have to be downloaded first from a remote repo). I don't see how a plugin is going to help me...

Comment: @Tunaki thanks, I'll check your sample

Comment: @Tunaki using your sample: how can I take the settings.xml file (mirrors, proxies, repositories etc.) into account and how can I get all transitive dependencies for the "runtime" scope?

Comment: Aether doesn't provide a way to read the Maven settings file, so you can either use the existing methods like `setMirrorSelector` and `setProxySelector` on the system session. But if you really want to read the Maven settings, using the `maven-settings-builder` library would be easier, [see also the sample code mentioned here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Creating_a_Repository_System_Session).

Comment: @Puce I made an edit regarding proxy and mirrors with Aether on the linked answer. Btw, what do you want to do with the dependencies after getting them?

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks! I need to dynamically configure a URLClassLoader which can resolve classes and resources from all dependencies defined by a POM file. Is there a way to get all transitive dependencies with "runtime" scope using Aether? The samples I found so far ony resolve all direct dependencies and I think e.g. "test" scope is included as well.

Comment: @Puce Yep, take a look at [`system.resolveDependencies`](http://download.eclipse.org/aether/aether-core/0.9.0/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystem.html#resolveDependencies(org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession,%20org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyRequest)). It takes a `DependencyRequest` as argument, on which you can set specific `DependencyFilter`, like [`ScopeDependencyFilter`](http://download.eclipse.org/aether/aether-core/0.9.0/apidocs/org/eclipse/aether/util/filter/ScopeDependencyFilter.html), which would retain only the dependencies with the given scope.

Comment: (Continued) But since the linked question was about direct dependencies, I will answer this one (tomorow, it's late now :) ) with how to fetch transitive dependencies with the filters. Could you edit with all of your requirements?

Comment: [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200497/how-to-programmatically-list-all-transitive-dependencies-including-overridden-o#70823705) is for use within a plugin, but may be usable outside as well if the `LifecycleDependencyResolver` can be properly instantiated; it doesn't have a direct dependency on Aether (although Maven would obviously use Aether under the hood)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Outside of a Maven plugin, the way to operate on artifacts is through Aether. The team has a sample project to get the transitive dependencies of a given artifact called [`ResolveTransitiveDependencies`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/aether/aether-demo.git/tree/aether-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/aether/examples/ResolveTransitiveDependencies.java). Once you have the Aether dependencies set up ([like shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641359/1743880)), you can simply have:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    RepositorySystem system = newRepositorySystem(locator);
    RepositorySystemSession session = newSession(system);

    RemoteRepository central = new RemoteRepository.Builder("central", "default", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/").build();

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("group.id:artifact.id:version");

    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest(new Dependency(artifact, JavaScopes.COMPILE), Arrays.asList(central));
    DependencyFilter filter = DependencyFilterUtils.classpathFilter(JavaScopes.COMPILE);
    DependencyRequest request = new DependencyRequest(collectRequest, filter);
    DependencyResult result = system.resolveDependencies(session, request);

    for (ArtifactResult artifactResult : result.getArtifactResults()) {
        System.out.println(artifactResult.getArtifact().getFile());
    }
}

private static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem(DefaultServiceLocator locator) {
    locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class, FileTransporterFactory.class);
    locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class);
    return locator.getService(RepositorySystem.class);
}

private static RepositorySystemSession newSession(RepositorySystem system) {
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();
    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository("target/local-repo");
    session.setLocalRepositoryManager(system.newLocalRepositoryManager(session, localRepo));
    return session;
}
```

It will download the artifacts and place them into `"target/local-repo"`.

Note that you can configure proxy and mirrors with the `DefaultProxySelector` and `DefaultMirrorSelector` on the system session. It would be possible to read the Maven settings file and use it to populate the session, but things get really ugly really fast...

---

When you want tight coupling with Maven itself because you have access to the POM to process and want to take the settings into account, it is a lot simpler to directly invoke Maven programmatically. In this case, you're interested in the path of each dependencies, including transitive dependencies, of a given POM file. For that the [`dependency:list`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) goal, together with setting the [`outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename) to `true`, will give (almost) exactly that.

To invoke Maven programmatically, it is possible to use the [Invoker API](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html). Adding the dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

you can have:

```
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile(new File(pomPath));
request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("dependency:list"));
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("outputFile", "dependencies.txt"); // redirect output to a file
properties.setProperty("outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename", "true"); // with paths
properties.setProperty("includeScope", "runtime"); // only runtime (scope compile + runtime)
// if only interested in scope runtime, you may replace with excludeScope = compile
request.setProperties(properties);

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
// the Maven home can be omitted if the "maven.home" system property is set
invoker.setMavenHome(new File("/path/to/maven/home"));
invoker.setOutputHandler(null); // not interested in Maven output itself
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(request);
if (result.getExitCode() != 0) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Build failed.");
}

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:compile|runtime):(.*)");
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("dependencies.txt"))) {
    while (!"The following files have been resolved:".equals(reader.readLine()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // group 1 contains the path to the file
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

This creates an invocation request which contains: the goals to invoke and the system properties, just like you would launch `mvn dependency:list -Dprop=value` on the command-line. The path to the settings to use will default to the standard location of `"${user.home}/settings.xml"`, but it would also be possible to specify the path to the settings with `request.setUserSettingsFile(...)` and `request.setGlobalSettingsFile(...)`. The invoker needs to be set the Maven home (i.e. installation directory), but only if the `"maven.home"` system property isn't set.

The result of invoking `dependency:list` is redirected to a file, that is later post-processed. The output of that goal consists of the list of dependencies in the format (the classifier may be absent, if there are none):

```
group.id:artifact.id:type[:classifier]:version:scope:pathname
```

There isn't a way to output only the path of the resolved artifact's file, and the fact that the classifier may be absent complicates the parsing a bit (we can't split on `:` with a limit, since the path could contain a `:`...). First, the resolved artifacts are below the line `"The following files have been resolved:"` in the output file, then, since the wanted scope are only `compile` or `runtime`, we can get the path of the artifact's file with a simple regular expression that takes everything which is after `compile:` or `runtime:`. That path can then directly be used as a `new File`.

If the hoops during post-processing look too fragile, I guess you could create your own plugin that just outputs the resolved artifact's filename.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to implement a first version with settings support.

Comment: Only note for those who are coming here and have one master _pom.xml_ file with modules it is useful to set `appendOutput` flag on `true` to have a list of all dependencies from all modules: `properties.setProperty("appendOutput", "true");` Otherwise each module will overwrite output from the previous one.

Comment: @Tunaki Can we achieve this use-case without having maven in the computer?

Comment: @Puce I'm trying to use the aether example. but I'm not able to resolve dependencies. I get exception `org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3`. I only changed the follwoing line in the above code. `Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3");`

Comment: Is there a working solution that uses Aether `4.0.0-alpha-2`?