# API to get dependency list of a given artifact without installing mvn

Tags: java, maven

I can get details of mvn artifacts and download artifacts using `https://search.maven.org/` API.

Is there a way to resolve dependencies and get a list of dependencies of a given mvn artifact using such an API?

**Example**:

For artifact `com.google.inject:guide:4.2.2`

I need the following list (`com.google.inject:guide:4.2.2` depends on following dependencies):

```
[com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.2:compile,
javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile,
aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile,
com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.1-android:compile]
```

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813062/maven-get-all-dependencies-programmatically ?

Comment: @JoachimRohde But I want to run the program without maven in my computer

Comment: As far as I understood you don't have to have Maven installed. You are just using code that is provided by Maven.