# How to access local maven repository in plexus component?

Tags: java, maven, plexus, maven-mojo

I am writing a custom DependencyAnalyzer which plugs into the `dependency:analyze` goal. The analyzer is a plexus component whose sole parameter is the `MavenProject` instance.

My analyzer needs access to the local repository to be able to invoke the `DependencyTreeBuilder` (from `org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree`), which is the same component used by `dependency:tree` in verbose mode.

I understand that in a mojo, I could use a parameter with the expression `"${localRepository}"` to get the required `ArtifactRepository` instance. However, I could not find a way to get the repository from the plexus component.

I managed to add a dependency to the `ArtifactRepositoryFactory` plexus component, but have no idea what to pass to its `createArtifactRepository()` method.

Is there any way to get the `ArtifactRepository`, or alternatively, a way to evaluate expressions from a plexus component?

---

Note: this is similar to [How to get access to Maven's dependency hierarchy within a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1492000/7641), but the code given there applies to a mojo, whereas I need the code in a plexus component.