# Find dependencies of a Maven Dependency object

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven 3 plugin that needs to know the transitive dependencies of a given `org.apache.maven.model.Dependency`. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the purpose of the plugin? Take a look into maven-dependency-plugin code....Apart from that didn't you define the DependencyResolution on the mojo ?

Comment: You need more than a `Dependency`. You need access to the `MavenProject` since the resolved transitive dependencies depends on potential conflict resolution.

Comment: @Tunaki I'm in a Maven 3 plugin, so I have a `MavenProject`, too.

Comment: @khmarbaise That code is all [deprecated in Maven 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492000/how-to-get-access-to-mavens-dependency-hierarchy-within-a-plugin). :-(

Comment: By the way, do you want all resolved dependencies, all dependencies (including excluded one), dependencies before or after conflict resolution?

Comment: @DanFabulich First you didn't answer my questions..Apart from that what code is exactly deprecated? Usually a plugin is always in the context of a project ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the following code should give you an impression how to do it.

```java
@Mojo( name = "test", requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE, defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE ...)
public class TestMojo
    extends AbstractMojo
{
    @Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true )
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute()
        throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        List<Dependency> dependencies = project.getDependencies();
        for ( Dependency dependency : dependencies )
        {
            getLog().info( "Dependency: " + getId(dependency) );
        }

        Set<Artifact> artifacts = project.getArtifacts();
        for ( Artifact artifact : artifacts )
        {
            getLog().info( "Artifact: " + artifact.getId() );
        }
    }

    private String getId(Dependency dep) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( dep.getGroupId() );
        sb.append( ':' );
        sb.append( dep.getArtifactId() );
        sb.append( ':' );
        sb.append( dep.getVersion() );
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

The above code will give you the resolved artifacts as well as dependencies. You need to make a difference between the dependencies (in this case the project dependencies without transitive and the artifacts which are the solved artifacts incl. transitive.).

Most important is `requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.COMPILE` otherwise you will get `null` for `getArtifacts()`.

The suggestion by Tunaki will work for any kind of artifact which is not part of your project...The question is what you really need?

Answer (score 8):

In Maven 3, you access all dependencies in a tree-based form by relying on the [`maven-dependency-tree`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-tree/) shared component:

> A tree-based API for resolution of Maven project dependencies.

This component introduces the `DependencyGraphBuilder` that can build the dependency tree for a given Maven project. You can also filter artifacts with a `ArtifactFilter`, that has a couple of built-in implementations to filter by groupId, artifactId (`IncludesArtifactFilter` and `ExcludesArtifactFilter`), scope (`ScopeArtifactFilter`), etc. If the fiter is `null`, all dependencies are kept.

In your case, since you target a specific artifact, you could add a `IncludesArtifactFilter` with the pattern `groupId:artifactId` of your artifact. A sample code would be:

```java
@Mojo(name = "foo")
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${session}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenSession session;

    @Component(hint = "default")
    private DependencyGraphBuilder dependencyGraphBuilder;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        ArtifactFilter artifactFilter = new IncludesArtifactFilter(Arrays.asList("groupId:artifactId"));
        ProjectBuildingRequest buildingRequest = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest(session.getProjectBuildingRequest());
        buildingRequest.setProject(project);
        try {
            DependencyNode rootNode = dependencyGraphBuilder.buildDependencyGraph(buildingRequest, artifactFilter);
            CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor();
            rootNode.accept(visitor);
            for (DependencyNode node : visitor.getNodes()) {
                System.out.println(node.toNodeString());
            }
        } catch (DependencyGraphBuilderException e) {
            throw new MojoExecutionException("Couldn't build dependency graph", e);
        }
    }

}
```

This gives access to the root node of the dependency tree, which is the current project. From that node, you can access all chidren by calling the `getChildren()` method. So if you want to list all dependencies, you can traverse that graph recursively. This component does provide a facility for doing that with the `CollectingDependencyNodeVisitor`. It will collect all dependencies into a `List` to easily loop through it.

For the Maven plugin, the following dependency is therefore necessary:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-tree</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Even though it is not utilizing the Dependency class but the DependencyNode class the example did exactly what I was looking for and should thus be the accepted answer.