# How to get "relocated" or resolved artifact ID from top-level dependencies in maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I may be going about this wrong, but I'm trying to get the top-level dependencies of a project within a maven plugin.

I can get all (top-level and transitive) dependencies using this call

```
MavenProject.getArtifacts()
```

I can get just the top-level dependencies using this call

```
MavenProject.getDependencyArtifacts()
```

The problem is that the artifactIds returned in the latter call is sometimes different than the artifactIds in the former call. This happens when the dependency is "relocated" such as xerces:xerces:2.4.0

```
 <project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xerces</groupId>
  <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
 </project>
```

If the developer specifies xerces:xerces:2.4.0 in their pom, getArtifacts() returns xerces:xercesImpl. But getDependencyArtifacts() returns xerces:xerces.

Comment: What is your Maven version? And the `maven-plugin-api` version for your plugin? Also, `getDependencyArtifacts()` is deprecated (may be the issue), direct dependencies are obtained with [`getDependencies()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getDependencies%28%29).

Comment: How is your plugin defined ? Does it define dependency resolution? Apart from that what's the purpose of the plugin?

Comment: @Tunaki Both mvn and maven-plugin-api are v3.3.3. I tried getDependencies(), but its getGroupId() and getArtifactId() return me the pre-relocated GAV

Comment: @khmarbaise Not sure what you mean by how my plugin is defined or whether it defines dependency resolution. The plugin is to read a developer's dependencies and display them in a 2-tiered way, distinguishing between direct and indirect dependencies

Comment: Reading the code, I'm not sure if it is a Maven bug or not =/. I was able to reproduce this behaviour. Put simply, `getDependencyArtifacts()` is populated with the strict list of dependencies of the project, without taking into account the relocation element. For the gory details of my debug session, this is done inside `LifecycleDependencyResolver` method `resolveProjectDependencies`. There is a clear different code path for `setDependencyArtifacts` and `setResolvedArtifacts`. The question now is: is this the expected result? What do you think @khmarbaise?

Comment: Artifact has a isResolved() method that returns false for these un-relocated artifacts. I was wondering if there is a way to relocate or resolve the artifact to get the relocated GAV. That is a perfectly valid solution as far as I'm concerned. I tried using ArtifactResolver.resolve(RepositorySystemSession, ArtifactRequest) but that didn't work out the way I expected

Comment: In that case, you could build the project in-memory [like I answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35457401/1743880). Then when you have the `MavenProject` based on the artifact, you can call `mavenProject.getDistributionManagement().getRelocation()` to access the relocation element. Still, this feels like a very hacky way =/.

Comment: @Tunaki your suggestion for using mavenProject.getDistributionManagement().getRelocation() worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Tunaki I also switched from the deprecated getDependencyArtifacts() to getDependencies(), but with a Dependency object, there's no API to check if it was resolved like the Artifact.isResolved(). Any ideas?

Comment: @kane Yes that's actually the real difference between a `Dependency` and an `Artifact`. A `Dependency` is just a dependency with its Maven coordinates. But an `Artifact` is a resolved dependency in the context of the project (maybe omitted, possible transitive artifacts etc...). So you won't find a "resolved" property for a `Dependency` since it only makes sense for `Artifact`s.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Tunaki. I'll make due with what I have